# comparar la fecha de una fila con la fecha de otra

Tags: php, mysql

saludos a todos, los molesto con una inquietud que tengo.

Actualmente estoy en un proyecto, soy nuevo en esto de la programación.
Es un página, hago una consulta a una BD mysql y la muestro usando un WHILE.

Siempre la consulta muestra una tabla con 6 columnas que contienen el id, una fecha, nombres, correos etc.

Yo lo que necesito saber es si hay una manera de comparar la fecha de una fila con la fecha de otra, ya que los registros suelen ser de meses diferentes y yo necesito mostrar, en el caso que aplique, cuantos meses hay entre uno y otro.

De antemano, gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Saludos!!

Comment: primero échale un ojo a DATEDIFF y sino pega tu código y sé un poco más específico en tu pregunta

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises la documentación para saber como realizar la pregunta correctamente en esta dirección: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask de esta forma te podremos ayudar mas fácil

Comment: Coloca un fragmento de código para ser mas eficaces en la respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

Aca dejo el codigo de la consulta. Como muestra ahí, de la base de datos me traigo un campo llamado fecha, esas fechas varían. Yo necesito saber si entre un registo (fila) de las que muestra el While, si hay meses en los que no se registraron datos. Ejemplo: tengo registros 3 registros con fechas (2017-09-12)(2017-11-12)(2017-12-12). Quiero saber si hay alguna manera de obtener ese lapso de tiempo entre el registro que tiene fecha de septiembre y el que tiene fecha de noviembre

$sql="SELECT * FROM facturas WHERE id=$'id'";

```
                        $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                        $contar=mysqli_num_rows($query);



                        if($contar>0){


                            echo"<table>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Nombre</td>
                                    <td>fecha</td>
                                    <td>pago</td>
                                </tr>";


                            while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


                                echo"
                                <tr>
                                    <td>$filaMT['nombre']</td>
                                    <td>$filaMT['fecha']</td>
                                    <td>$filaMT['pago']</td>
                                </tr>";
                            }

                            echo"</table>";
```